# Multiple definition of Variable while it is not

Tags: linker-errors, mplab, multiple-definition-error

I am trying to compile an empty project using MPLAB X IDE. I have just used mcc (microchip code configurator) to make the first configuration of the clock only.
mcc generated a bunch of header files and source files such as " traps.c , traps.h, system.h ...etc"
When I compile my project it gives me two kinds of repeated errors, e.g:
1- `mcc_generated_files/traps.c:121: multiple definition of` `__MathError` 
while there is no variable defined by `__MathError`. There is only function defined '_MathError' ***one underscore***.

2- `c:\program files (x86)\microchip\xc16\v1.35\bin\bin\..\bin/elf-ld.exe: Link Error: section .config_CPRE15%22 [015f78 -> 015f79 ] overlaps section .config_CPRE15%5 [015f78 -> 015f79 ]`

I read that it is about including .c files. However, I didn't include any .c files neither the MCC and there is no variable definition in header files.
what is wrong with this compilation.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem just now.  It was introduced when I:

1. started a pic24 template project (which built fine of course)
2. started adding timers using MCC (mplab code configurator)
3. then the build would fail for I think the same issues you have above

The issue was that the template already had a "traps.c" in the main Project.X folder, and so Project.X/mcc_generated_files/traps.c caused all sorts of compile headaches.  Simple fix.  Just remove the one in the generated code area by right clicking and say remove from project.  You also needs to remove the traps.h from the header area.

Comment: I didn't use any template project. So I don't have another traps.c source file inside the project file. However, I guess it is in another location and the compiler includes it also. Your answer was helpful. Thank you.